# Error decoding JSON and broken logs in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

i'm using elk stack of version 5.5 in ubuntu 16.0

My logs are getting broken and not writting properly into elastic which is resulting in json.erros

like below

```
Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'e' in literal null (expecting 'u')"
```

getting json.errors very frequent and those logs are not reading or writting properly into elasticsearch ?

and this is happening for every 5 to 10 mins. please help me solve it.

[screenshot of broken logs in kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck0ou.png)

My sample log is :

`{"log":"2019-10-01 07:18:26:854*[DEBUG]*cluster2-nio-worker-0*Connection*userEventTriggered*Connection[cassandraclient/10.3.254.137:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-10-01T07:18:26.85462769Z"}`

Comment: Yeah, this has been fixed but you have to upgade es version. Take a look at: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/6045

Comment: Can you please share the filebeat prospector configuration for that particular file? And also: Are your JSON objects in the log file pretty-printed, meaning they span over multiple lines?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @apt-get_install_skill                                                 The following is my filebeat configuration :                                           ``filebeat.registry_file: /var/log/containers/filebeat_registry
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - "/var/log/containers/*.log"
  tags: ["kube-logs"]
  symlinks: true
  json.message_key: log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
  multiline.negate: true 
  multiline.match: after``

Comment: Are your JSON objects in the log file pretty-printed, meaning they span over multiple lines?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill no they are not pretty printed anyway the following log is my sample log :                                                                                                           `{"log":"2019-10-01 07:18:26:854*[DEBUG]*cluster2-nio-worker-0*Connection*userEventTriggered*Connection[cassandraclient/10.3.254.137:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-10-01T07:18:26.85462769Z"}`

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill i have attached as you requested.

Comment: @Vamsi Vutukuri have you had any success with my suggested solution?

Comment: @Vamsi Vutukuri Youre welcome! I would appreciate if you would accept my answer and give me an upvote if you feel satisfied.

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill i already did but it showing the following pop : 
 Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated that the json logs are not pretty printed I assume that the multiline-settings of your input configuration are causing the problems.

In my opinion you don't need any multiline settings when you have logs in json format **and** they are not pretty printed, meaning the whole json object (= log event) is written in one line.

You have already specified

> json.message_key: log

This solely should get the job done.

**So to sum it up:**

Remove the multiline settings and try again. Your configuration should look like this:

```
filebeat.inputs: 
  - type: log 
    paths: 
      - "/var/log/containers/*.log"
    tags: ["kube-logs"]
    symlinks: true 
    json.message_key: log
    json.keys_under_root: true 
    json.add_error_key: true
```